# Debounce in Redux Toolkit

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, react-tsx

I'm Trying to debounce below API call with using lodash `debounce`

```
export const getProfile = createAsyncThunk(
  GET_PROFILE,
  async (amount: any, { rejectWithValue }: any) => {
    try {
      const response = await API.Get(EndPoint.GET_PROFILE)
      console.log(response)
      return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
      amount.failCallBack(error?.response?.data?.msg || 'something_went_wrong')
      return rejectWithValue(error?.code || 'Something went wrong..!')
    }
  }
)
```

above function is worked without any errors and fetch data able to see inside `fulfilled` of the action

so I tried to implement debounce as below way

```
export const getProfile = createAsyncThunk(
  GET_PROFILE,
  debounce(async (amount: any, { rejectWithValue }: any) => {
    try {
      const response = await API.Get(EndPoint.GET_PROFILE)
      console.log(response)
      return response.data
    } catch (error: any) {
      amount.failCallBack(error?.response?.data?.msg || 'something_went_wrong')
      return rejectWithValue(error?.code || 'Something went wrong..!')
    }
  }, 5000)
)
```

Now there is no any exceptions in web app and when I `console.log` the `fulfilled` action it shows `payload` as `undefined`

```js
{
    "type": "login/getProfile/fulfilled",
    "meta": {
        "arg": {
            "data": "login"
        },
        payload: undefined,
        "requestId": "8pfalpIzFl8nNOgi2jRcb",
        "requestStatus": "fulfilled"
    }
}
```

any suggestions for fix this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't debounce the payload creator - debounce dispatching the thunk action. And since you probably don't want to that in your component, do it in a manual thunk

```js
const getProfile = createAsyncThunk( ... normal definition ... );
const debounced = debounce((arg, dispatch) => dispatch(getProfile(arg)), 5000);
const debouncedGetProfile = (arg) => (dispatch) => debounced(arg, dispatch)
```

and then use that

```
dispatch(debouncedGetProfile(amount))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You could fix the missing parenthesis on the second line.

Comment: @hlustosa good catch, fixed it.

Comment: `Don't debounce the payload creator - debounce dispatching the thunk action`
@phry why is this approach preferred over debouncing within the redux store / thunk? I am trying to justify why every dispatcher should need to care about debouncing the actions it emits, seems less clean / scalable.

Example alternative: https://gist.github.com/sarakusha/bb63f1a4a0143afc257eca57f2acc5f2

Comment: @dclaze building a manual solution around this will probably make it better, but you will still end up with a ton of unnecessary actions flying around that might clobber your action log. I'd personally try to avoid that if it nicely can be avoided. But I agree, your solution works over multiple components, which is nice.